# How to check my outgoing network traffic for my home network?

Tags: networking

How can I check my outgoing network traffic?

In particular I have something like

```
[fiber modem ipv6]->[router]-+->[ap]->[wireless devices]
                             |
                             +->[switch]->[wired devices]
```

Assume it's possible my router or my modem is hacked or any of my devices. How would I check? Is there some device I can put in front of the modem (provided by my ISP) that could show me a list of outgoing connections?

Comment: The `modem -> router` link is just regular Ethernet, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by using a pc as a gateway to network. This is possible by acting as a gateway to your router. You just have to use linux ( kali linux for ease) and connect yourself to router. Then, you can intercept the network using some useful tools such as wireshark. Or you can edit the gateway IP on each of your devices to your pc and analyse the traffic with tools available both on linux and windows.